# How to store an image in the database android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-image

I am new to android and I am creating a contact manager. I have worked out how to store the values from EditText fields into the database but I don't know how to store an image in the database. I was wondering if someone could help me with this.

```
package awad865.project.ContactManager1;



import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class AddContact extends Activity {
    //declare private fields
    private EditText firstName;
    private EditText lastName;
    private EditText number;
    private EditText address;
    private EditText date;
    private EditText email;
    private Spinner numberSpinner;
    private Spinner emailSpinner;
    private Spinner addressSpinner;
    private Spinner dateSpinner;
    private DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
    private ImageButton addPic;
    private final int IMAGE_SELECTION =1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_contact);
        //code that enables the title on the action bar
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        //intialise private fields
        firstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_first_name);
        lastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_last_name);
        number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_number);
        address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_address);
        date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_date);
        email =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_email);


        //Spinner for the phone number field
        numberSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.contact_number_spinner);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.number_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        numberSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        //Spinner for the email address field
        emailSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.contact_email_spinner);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
                R.array.email_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        emailSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Spinner for address field
        addressSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.contact_address_spinner);
        adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.address_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        addressSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Spinner for date
        dateSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.contact_date_spinner);
        adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
                R.array.date_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dateSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        addPic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addImage);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.contacts_photo);
        addPic.setImageBitmap(bm);

        addPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                imageIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(imageIntent, IMAGE_SELECTION);

            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch(requestCode){
        case IMAGE_SELECTION:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                try{
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inScaled = true;
                    final Uri imageURI = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    final InputStream inStr = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageURI);
                    final Bitmap selectImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStr, null, options);
                    addPic.setImageBitmap(selectImg);
                }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                    Log.e("File not found", "Selected image was not found", ex);
                }
            }
        }

    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_contact, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        switch(item.getItemId()){
        //if the save button is pressed, then all the information is retrieved from the EditText fields
        //and stored in the private fields and then a new contact object is created and added to the 
        //database
        case R.id.action_save:
                    //WANT to save the image here
            BitmapDrawable bmd = ((BitmapDrawable) addPic.getDrawable());
            Bitmap photo = bmd.getBitmap();
            Contact contact = new Contact(firstName.getText().toString(),lastName.getText().toString(),number.getText().toString(), numberSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), email.getText().toString(), emailSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), date.getText().toString(), dateSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), address.getText().toString(), addressSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), "false");
            //add to database

            try {
                databaseHandler.openDataBase();
                databaseHandler.addContact(contact);
                databaseHandler.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                throw sqle;
            }
            //go back to list of contacts
            Intent intentMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intentMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intentMain);
            return true;

            //if the cancel button is pressed on the action bar then the user is navigate to MainActivity
        case R.id.action_cancel:
            Intent intentCancel = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            intentCancel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intentCancel);
            return true;
            //if the up button is pressed, then the user is taken back to the MainActivity
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
}
```

My DatabaseHandler class:

```
package awad865.project.ContactManager1;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //declaring contants
    private static String DB_NAME = "ContactsDb";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/awad865.project.ContactManager1/databases/";
    private final Context myContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACT = "Contact";
    private static final String FIRST_NAME = "firstname";
    private static final String LAST_NAME = "lastname";
    private static final String NUMBER = "number";
    private static final String NUMBER_TYPE = "numbertype";
    private static final String EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String EMAIL_TYPE = "emailtype";
    private static final String DATE = "date";
    private static final String DATE_TYPE = "datetype";
    private static final String ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String ADDRESS_TYPE = "addresstype";
    private static final String IMAGE = "image";
    private static final String FAVOURITE = "favourite";


    //the parent constructor is called
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }
    //method for creating the database
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(dbExist){
            //copyDataBase();
        }else{
            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //database does't exist yet.
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local database as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty database
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Open the empty database as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }
    //method for adding a contact to the database
    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //put all the appropriate edit text fields contact and store them in the database.
        values.put(FIRST_NAME, contact.getFirstName()); 
        values.put(LAST_NAME, contact.getLastName()); 
        values.put(NUMBER, contact.getNumber()); 
        values.put(NUMBER_TYPE, contact.getNumberType());
        values.put(EMAIL, contact.getEmail()); 
        values.put(EMAIL_TYPE, contact.getEmailType());
        values.put(ADDRESS, contact.getAddress()); 
        values.put(ADDRESS_TYPE, contact.getAddressType());
        values.put(DATE, contact.getDate()); 
        values.put(DATE_TYPE, contact.getDateType());
        values.put(FAVOURITE, "false");
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACT, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(String firstName, String lastName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACT,
                FIRST_NAME + "=? AND " + LAST_NAME + "=?", 
                new String[] {firstName, lastName});
        db.close();
    }

    //this method is used for editing a contact
    public int updateContact(Contact contact, String firstName, String lastName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //we first find the existing contact, and overwrite the old
        //values with the new values
        values.put(FIRST_NAME, contact.getFirstName()); 
        values.put(LAST_NAME, contact.getLastName());
        values.put(NUMBER, contact.getNumber()); 
        values.put(NUMBER_TYPE, contact.getNumberType());
        values.put(EMAIL, contact.getEmail()); 
        values.put(EMAIL_TYPE, contact.getEmailType());
        values.put(ADDRESS, contact.getAddress()); 
        values.put(ADDRESS_TYPE, contact.getAddressType());
        values.put(DATE, contact.getDate()); 
        values.put(DATE_TYPE, contact.getDateType());
        values.put(FAVOURITE, contact.getFavourite());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACT, values, FIRST_NAME + "=? AND " + LAST_NAME + "=?",
                new String[] {firstName, lastName});
    }

    public List<Contact> getFavouriteContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        String isFavourite = "true";
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACT + " WHERE " + FAVOURITE + "='" + isFavourite + "'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(11));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return contactList;
    }


    public Contact getContact(String firstName, String lastName) {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACT + " WHERE " + FIRST_NAME + "='" + firstName + "' AND " + LAST_NAME + "='" + lastName + "'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(11));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return contactList.get(0);
    }




    public List<Contact> getContacts(String order) {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        //this bottom line is used to change the sorting order of the contact list
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACT +" ORDER BY " + order;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(11));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return contactList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you could use BLOB in you database, convert the image to byte array and store in database.

You can also refer the following links to get a fair and clear idea about it:

[How to save images into Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512019/how-to-save-images-into-database).

[How to store image in SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database)

[how to store Image as blob in Sqlite & how to retrieve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it)

[how to store and retrieve images in android SQLite database and display them on a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831151/how-to-store-and-retrieve-images-in-android-sqlite-database-and-display-them-on)

[how to save and retrive images from sql lite database in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840504/how-to-save-and-retrive-images-from-sql-lite-database-in-android)

[Android How to save camera images in database and display another activity in list view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941637/android-how-to-save-camera-images-in-database-and-display-another-activity-in-li)

Answer (score 1):

this is your code for insert image in database.

```
  db=new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();

    byte[] img=Utilities.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cute));

    db.insert(img);
    byte[] b=db.fetchSingle(1);
    img1.setImageBitmap(Utilities.getImage(img));
    db.close();
```

and this is utility class

```
public class Utilities {
   public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap)
   {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,0, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
   }
   public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image)
   {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
   }

}
```