# Store image in sqlite from variable

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, store

I created this database

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query="CREATE TABLE "+tableName+" ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            col1+" INTEGER, "+col2+" String, "+col3+" String, "+col4+" String );";
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

to sotre an image with some informations in a list
I get the image from the user

```
public void openGallery(View view){
    Intent open = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    open.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(open,100);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==100){
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap decodeStream = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            img.setImageBitmap(decodeStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }



}
```

and I put the image in the variable "img" >             img.setImageBitmap(decodeStream);

how do I save it in the database base ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store an image in the database android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538966/how-to-store-an-image-in-the-database-android)

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19539176/3505534

Comment: Try this... http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/23/store-image-android-sqlite-retrieve-it/

Comment: Follow the steps from following link http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/23/store-image-android-sqlite-retrieve-it/